# android 4.4 phone not charaging and no sync when pluged into computer

Tags: charging, usb-debugging, system

My phone

- manufacture: Samsung
- Model number: sm-j110f
- android version: 4.4.4
- rooted: Yes

Charging only works if

- Phone is turned off
- Phone is in recovery mode
- Phone is plunged into an ac charger.

Connection to computer only works if

- Phone is in recovery mode adb
- Phone is in Download mode

things i have tried

- flash stock firmware with Odin

  I don't know how to start to trouble shot this issue or fix it.

I would like to be able to charge my phone when plugged into the computer and copy pull files off the phone.

Comment: Did you try changing the USB cable? Also tried from a different USB port on the computer ? On a different computer?

Comment: @beeshyams yep even tried on an Linux operating system.

Comment: @beeshyams don't have any custom ROMs for my phone.

Comment: @beeshyams its not a faulty port. the port works fine if its in download mode.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by using the oldest firmware build on [sammobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-J110F/VAP/) i thought the newer firmware build would be better but flashing an older firmware build fixed all my usb problems.